# Python: equivalent to Ruby's a = [0..200]

Tags: python, arrays, list

Is there an equivalent in Python of Ruby's `array = [0..200]`? It should produce an array (or list in Python's parlance) of integers from `0` to `200`.

Comment: What does `[0...200]` produce in Ruby?

Comment: In Ruby, `[0...200]` is an array of one `Range` element, how is that useful in practice? Perhaps you mean `(0...200).to_a`?

Comment: Not familiar with ruby, but it sounds like `range(0, 200)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Signal! Don't know why this is being downvoted, but I'm happy.

Comment: AFAIK python does not have a range data type, so there is no equivalence.

Comment: `0...200` produces a Range object. `[0...200]` produces an Array with a single element, which is that Range object. I suspect OP really wants to know the Python equivalent to `(0...200).to_a` or `[*0...200]`, both of which will produce an array with the integers 0 through 199.

Comment: Bingo, sorry. I should have been clearer. I'll update the question so the answer reflects it.

Comment: @Signal just waiting for the timer to let me. :)

Comment: @CD-RUM Gotcha! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following in Python:

```
range(0, 200)
```

Comment: Note however that in ruby 0..200 is inclusive of the last value so it generates a list of 201 elements that includes 200.  In python range parameters are exclusive.